# Implicit conversion/promotion of float or double in expressions between C# and Java

Tags: c#, java

If I have the following expression:

```
byte A = 69;
int B = 123;
long C = 3210;
float D = 4.9f;
double E = 11.11;

double X = (B * 100) + 338.1 - (E / B) / C;
double X1 = (B * 100) + (A * D) - (E / B) / C;

// JAVA - lost precision
System.out.println(X);  // 12638.099971861307
System.out.println(X1); // 12638.099581236307

// C# - almost the same
Console.WriteLine(X);  // 12638.0999718613
Console.WriteLine(X1)  // 12638.0999784417
```

I noticed that Java loses precision from X where 338.1 is implicit double while C# almost doesn't. I don't understand why because 338.1 is equals in float and in double. There is only one digit after the dot.

Comment: 338.1 is NOT identical in float and double.  The exact binary expansion of 338.1 repeats forever, so when expressed as a double, it has a whole lot more non-zero digits than when expressed as float.

Comment: please read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `(B * 100) + (A * D)` will be a float; and it will be the float that is closest to 12638.1.  However, 12638 requires 14 digits to express in binary, including the initial 1; which leaves 10 digits of the significand to express the fractional part.  Therefore, you're going to get the closest number of 1024ths to 0.1 - which is 102/1024.  This turns out to be 0.099609375 - so the float has a rounding error of 0.000390625.

That seems to be the difference between X and X1 that you're getting in your Java program.

I'm afraid I'm not a C# expert, so I can't tell you why C# is different.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the compilers interpretation of your expression. As you have not specified any intermediate type conversions, the compiler performs the `A * D` as first type conversion and then multiplication, instead of the reverse which you would expect. This might seem like a strange result, but it is a way for the compiler to give you a more exact result without you having to specify tedious type conversions.

Java does not handle this for you, and so `(B * 100) + (A * D)` is the multiplication of an `int` and a `float` - resulting in a `float`. This can be simulated in C# like this:

```
double X2 = (float)((B * 100) + (A * D)) - (E / B) / C;
Console.WriteLine("X2: {0}", X2);
```

This is one of the advantages (or dis-advantages some would probably say) of a high-level compiler.